# How to solve a BKN* Port Issue on a cisco catalyst

Tags: cisco, router, vlan, cisco-catalyst, spanning-tree

There is a Cisco ISR 4451 connected with Portchannel to a Catalyst 3850 Stack and there are some VLANs enabled, but only one does not come up for a Portinconsistence. I figure out an Issue on the equipment behind my catalyst stack but do not know how to debug this issue.

For better understanding here is a simple sketch of the Network:
[image: network sketch]

There are three VLANs on the ISR and Catalyst. The Portchannel act as a trunk and the Interfaces use access VLAN and one VLAN is for native VLAN. The VLAN 410 works fine but one VLAN 409 I get a type inconsistent error.

```
*%SPANTREE-7-RECV_1Q_NON_TRUNK: Received 802.1Q BPDU on non-trunk GigabitEthernet1/0/3 VLAN409.
*%SPANTREE-7-BLOCK_PORT_TYPE: Blocking GigabitEthernet1/0/3 on VLAN0409. Inconsistent port type.
```

Here is the config from catalyst Ports:

```
interface Port-channel2
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport mode trunk
end
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description PortChannel ISR
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 2 mode on
end
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 switchport access vlan 409
end
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 switchport access vlan 410
end
```

And this is the config of the ISR Ports

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 no ip address
 media-type sfp
 negotiation auto
 channel-group 2
end
interface Port-channel2.409
 encapsulation dot1Q 409
 ip address 10.1.18.5 255.255.255.252
end
interface Port-channel2.410
 encapsulation dot1Q 410
 ip address 10.1.18.1 255.255.255.252
end
```

Both interfaces are configured the same way, one works and the other one not. How can I debug this case and solve this issue?

The Output of sh spanning-tree show me the Port is broken, but I do not know why. Maybe any misconfiguration on the other side of the link? 
sh spanning-tree vlan 409

```
VLAN0409
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    33176
             Address     00a2.89b2.0f80
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    33176  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 409)
             Address     00a2.89b2.0f80
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  300 sec

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi1/0/3             Desg BKN*4         128.3    P2p *TYPE_Inc 
Po2                 Desg FWD 3         128.2316 P2p
```

**UPDATE**

complete Configuration:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 9280 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 12:08:55 UTC Tue Sep 11 2018
!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname cat03
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
vrf definition Mgmt-vrf
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv6
 exit-address-family
!
!
no aaa new-model
switch 1 provision ws-c3850-12s
switch 2 provision ws-c3850-12s
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip domain-name demo.de
!
!
qos queue-softmax-multiplier 100
!
!
!
errdisable recovery cause udld
errdisable recovery cause bpduguard
errdisable recovery cause security-violation
errdisable recovery cause channel-misconfig
errdisable recovery cause pagp-flap
errdisable recovery cause dtp-flap
errdisable recovery cause link-flap
errdisable recovery cause sfp-config-mismatch
errdisable recovery cause gbic-invalid
errdisable recovery cause l2ptguard
errdisable recovery cause psecure-violation
errdisable recovery cause port-mode-failure
errdisable recovery cause dhcp-rate-limit
errdisable recovery cause pppoe-ia-rate-limit
errdisable recovery cause mac-limit
errdisable recovery cause vmps
errdisable recovery cause storm-control
errdisable recovery cause inline-power
errdisable recovery cause arp-inspection
errdisable recovery cause loopback
errdisable recovery cause psp
errdisable recovery interval 60
diagnostic bootup level minimal
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
hw-switch switch 1 logging onboard message level 3
hw-switch switch 2 logging onboard message level 3
!
redundancy
 mode sso
!
!
vlan configuration 100,408-410
!
!
class-map match-any non-client-nrt-class
!
policy-map port_child_policy
 class non-client-nrt-class
  bandwidth remaining ratio 10
!
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel2
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-vrf
 ip address 10.1.20.60 255.255.255.0
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description PortChannel ISR
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 2 mode on
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 switchport access vlan 409
 spanning-tree bpduguard disable
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 switchport access vlan 410
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/3
!         
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/4
!         
interface Vlan409
 no ip address
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
!
!
snmp-server community private RO
snmp-server trap-source GigabitEthernet0/0
!
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 0 0
 login local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 exec-timeout 0 0
 login local
 transport input ssh
!         
!
wsma agent exec
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent config
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent filesys
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent notify
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
!
wsma profile listener httplistener
 transport http
!
wsma profile listener httpslistener
 transport https
!
ap group default-group
end
```

Comment: How are the ports connected? You cannot connect an access port to a trunk port.

Comment: The Ports are connected with fibre from Catalyst to other equipment of diffrent provider. But the configuration of the provider equipment I do not know. If I configure the IP Address on the Interface gi1/0/3 than it works. Is it a case of the remote provider? The provider told me that they do not configure any VLAN on his side.

Comment: Could you please add a simple diagram of how everything is connected? What ports are connected together.

Comment: I have edit the question and add a simple sketch

Comment: So it looks like the port-channel between the ISR and catalyst works as intended. You need to change your port Gi1/0/3 on your catalyst to a trunk port. `no switchport access vlan 409` `switchport mode trunk` `switchport trunk allowed vlan 409` That should remove the BPDUguard error.

Comment: but then the Traffic pass the network tagged and the provide do not accept vlans. So the traffic wouldnt reach the destination. The provider told me that the traffic should come untagged therefor I use switchport access vlan

Comment: You can disable BPDUguard, but personally i would talk to the provider and ask them what exactly they want. Command to disable BPDUguard: `spanning-tree bpduguard disable`

Comment: To clarify a possible misconception: "There are three VLANs on the ISR and Catalyst.". _Yes_ for the catalyst, _No_ for an ISR _router_ (without a switch module or advanced bridging configuration). A router has no notion of a VLAN in the sense of "virtual bridge", as a switch has. It just has physical interfaces (like `gig0/0/0` or `port-channel2`) and optionally subinterfaces thereof (`port-channel2.10`) which have a 802.1q tag. IPv4/v6 addresses may be assigned to interfaces or subinterfaces, although usually not simultaneously on interface and subinterface of the same interface.

Comment: @cown I try the block command but the port is still blocked.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi the VLANs are not added as Interface on ISR only as Subinterface with encapsulation, you are right.

Comment: @kockiren do you have error disable recovery?

Comment: @kockiren `errdisable recovery cause all` `errdisable recovery interval 60`

Comment: I have shut and no shut the Port but also enter the errdisable comand. Sh log told me that the port is inconstistent and blocked.

Comment: It takes 1 minute for the recovery to happen.

Comment: sh spanning-tree show me also BKN* State for the gi1/0/3 device the command is setup 5 minutes ago

Comment: Post a full updated configuration.

Comment: @cown The question was updated with the complete current configuration.

Comment: @kockiren use `switchport mode access` the port is in dynamic mode and therefore negotiates a trunk.

Comment: No change, I add switchport mode access to the interface gi1/0/3 and still the same. The Port is blocked with reason inconsistent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device connected to port 1/0/3 appears to be trunking, despite what your ISP claims.  The simple way to fix it is to make your interface a trunk as well:

```
interface gi 1/0/3
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 409
switchport trunk native vlan 409
```

Packets for vl 409 will pass untagged.

**EDIT:**

By using

```
debug spanning-tree
```

it was determined that the ISP was using a different VLAN (929)for the native VLAN despite their claim to the contrary.

So, when troubleshooting this kind of issue, the switch debug messages can give you insight into the problem.  The debug messages can provide important details on exactly what the mismatch is, allowing you to adjust your configuration.

Comment: After changing the Inteface the way you mentioned the issue is still the same. sh spanning-tree vlan 409 show me the interface gi1/0/3 as BKN*

Comment: If it stays in that state after resetting the interface, then you need to ask your ISP for their config on that port.  They have something misconfigured. As an alternative, you can turn off CDP: `no cdp enable`

Comment: I have opened a Ticket on ISP Site and waiting for a answer, as you mentioned I add no cdp enable to the interface but also no change. The Port is still in BKN* state

Comment: Another idea:  debug spanning-tree and then reset the port.  The log messages may give you more detail about what is going wrong.

Comment: I have enabled the debug and found this line: `STP SW: vlan409 Gi1/0/3: pvid inc peer vlan929` is it right that the provider use VLAN929 as trunk vlan?

Comment: I have change the vlan ID to the one from debug log and it works now, @rontrunk do you want to add the steps to your answer then I can mark the answer as accepted. First debug the spanning-tree and use the peer VLAN ID as trunking and native ID in my config. Add a subinterface on ISR with the new VLAN ID and now it works.